# position floated element inside a div of text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div (#bio) that is full of text. The content comes from a database call. Then I have another div that is a quote. I want to put the quote inside the text, have it float:right and have it about 30% from the top of the text.

But I'm having trouble. My quote always appears at the end of my bio text, not somewhere in the middle. How can I inject the quote into the middle somewhere of the bio text, please?

If it helps to understand, the bio text has HTML paragraphs throughout it.

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
            <h1></h1>
            <div class="quote"></div>
            <div id="bio"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", function(data){ //grab data from database via php
    var json = $.parseJSON(data); //parse the json so we can use it
    $.each(json, function(key, data) { 
        if (data.Country == 'USA') {
                            $('.text #bio').html(data.Notes);
            $('.quote').html('"' + data.Quote + '"');
            $('#bio').append($('.quote'));
            $('.quote').css({
                'margin-top': '30%',
                'float': 'right',
                'display': 'block'
            });

         }//end if
    });//end each   
   });//end post
```

CSS:

```
#bio .quote {
        color: lightgray;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 150%;
        color: #333;
        font-family:"Lora", serif;
        line-height:1.7em;
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #afb0a9;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #bcd1d9;
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }

.text
        {
        margin-left: 256px;
        font-family:"Muli", sans-serif;
        font-size:12pt;
        line-height:1.7em;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        }
#bio { position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not the easiest to achieve. I would recommend *not* doing this at all, but here is a general solution that might work.

1. You'll need some sort of container element that holds all the text
2. Measure 30% of the offsetHeight of that container element
3. Find the first `<p>` tag inside the container that is >= 30% the way down
4. Pluck the quote element from the DOM and insert it before the paragraph tag.

Comment: What makes you not recommend doing this?

Comment: This is almost the solution--I ended up using $("#bio p:nth-child(3)").append($('.quote')); (append the quote after the third paragraph of the bio)

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript required for the positioning :)
Just `float:right` on the quote and put it inside of the content (around 30% from the start):

```
<p>One Two Three
<q>This is a quote</q>
Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten</p>
```

with the CSS:

```
q {
    float: right;
}
```

Style as necessary.

The tough part is measuring '30% from the top'. Maybe do that in JavaScript, and inject the quote tag there?

```
$('p').html(
    data.Notes.substr(0, data.Notes.length / 3) +
    "<q>" + data.Quote + "</q>" + 
    data.Notes.substr(data.Notes.length / 3, data.Notes.length)
);
```

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/sX6EW/2/

Comment: Can't do this -- it's coming from a database, with other users filling it in.

Comment: @LauraNMS Edited. The key with the dynamically generated content is where to insert the `q` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bio p:nth-child(3)").append($('.quote'));
```

(append the quote after the third paragraph of the bio)

Comment: But if `#bio` has only 3 paragraphs or 100 paragraphs, it wouldn't really be 30%...